# Why MKTileOverlay initWithURLTemplate: template returns nil?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mktileoverlay

I have a code like below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString* template = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://my-map-server.com/?mode=tile&tilemode=gmap&tile={x}+{y}+{z}"] ;

MKTileOverlay * overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template]; //returns nil
overlay.canReplaceMapContent = NO;

[mainMap addOverlay:overlay1 level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];

}
```

Why `[[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template]` is returning `nil` value? I can't find any reasonable solution. Similar code works in my other project.

Answer (score 0):

> This template string should incorporate the `{x}`, `{y}`, `{z}`, and `{scale}` placeholder strings to facilitate the creation of a URL for requesting the appropriate tile.

If you add `{scale}` to your template, do you get the same result?